# How to declare HashMap with different types?

Tags: java, types, hashmap, declaration

I have a function, declared like this:

```
public synchronized void update(HashMap<String, Comparable> data)
```

data contains strings and ints, but the Comparable gives a warning

```
Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable<T> should be 
 parameterized
```

As I'm not overly found of warnings, question is, is there a correct way, I don't want to suppress the warning.

Thank in advance!
Marcus

Comment: A Comparable is for a specific type. You can't compare cross data types. That's why the warning asks you to restrict your Comparable to a specific type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should please the compiler:

```
public synchronized void update(HashMap<String, Comparable<Object>> data)
```

`Object` being the most specific supertype of both `String` and `Integer`. Also there is space for improvement in your code. First of all rely on `Map` interface, not on concrete `HashMap` implementation. Secondly if you don't really need the `Comparable` functionality, just use `Map<String, Object>`. Last but not least, avoid multi-type collections and prefer strong typing.

"*[...]data contains strings and ints[...]*" - if it's just a map from `String` to `Integer`:

```
public synchronized void update(HashMap<String, Integer> data)
```

Comment: `HashMap<String, Comparable<?>>` is neater.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't insist on a `HashMap` in your signature. Why not just a `Map`? Second, you should allow the map value type be anything *implementing* `Comparable`. Third, the `Comparable` itself can be parameterized with an unbounded wildcard:

```
void update(Map<String, ? extends Comparable<?>> data)
```

Now you can call it with any of `HashMap<String, Integer>`, `TreeMap<String, String>` or `SortedMap<String, Comparable<?>>`.